# pandas: is one column a substring of another column

Tags: python, pandas, string

I'm trying to test if one column (surname) is a substring of another column (name) in a dataframe (el). I've tried the following but python doesn't like it

```
el.name.str.contains(el.surname)
```

I can see plenty of examples of how to search for a literal substring, but not where the substring is a column.
Going mad on this one, help please!

Dave

Comment: can you share the dataframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
import pandas as pd

dct = {'surname': ['Smith', 'Miller', 'Mayer'],
       'name': ['Dr. John Smith', 'Nobody', 'Prof. Dr. Mayer']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dct)

df['is_part_of_name'] = df.apply(lambda x: x["surname"] in x["name"], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Which yields

```
  surname             name  is_part_of_name
0   Smith   Dr. John Smith             True
1  Miller           Nobody            False
2   Mayer  Prof. Dr. Mayer             True
```